# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null, stuck

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the

text when i press my h1 tag. This is my HMTL-code:

```
   <DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="tittel" title=“Når denne klikkes på, endres avsnittet”>Tittel </h1> <p id=”første” title=“Når denne klikkes på, sentreres tittelen”> Første avsnitt: original versjon.</p> 

    </body>
    <script src="2103.js"></script>
</html>
```

And JS:

```
var h1 = document.getElementById("tittel");
var avsnitt = document.getElementById("første");


function changeText() {
    avsnitt.innerHTML = "Første avsnitt: endret versjon";
}

h1.addEventListener("click", changeText());
```

Comment: change `id=”første”` to `id="første"` .. I'm not trusting ” characters..

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the `changeText` as a callback, not invoke it when using `addEventListener` like so:

```
h1.addEventListener("click", changeText);
```

When your code reaches the `changeText()` part it will invoke the function, return `undefined` (because the function has no return value) and the callback will not be registered.

The way `addEventListener` works is expecting to give a function (either as reference or literal) - but here you're giving `undefined`.

That's why the above works. It could also work with a function literal:

```
h1.addEventListener("click", function() { changeText(); });
```

Comment: this should work, but also change the ” quotes to " as @Pogrindis said in the comment

Comment: That is true, but it's not the problem. Even when you execute the function immediately when using addEventListener, `avsnitt` should be assigned and this error shouldn't occur. I think Pogrindis's comment is closer to the actual problem at hand, although your answer might very well address Joachim's next question. ;)

Comment: Both of the answers fixed my problem! Thank you so much! Why exactly can't I have changetext())? I was under the impression that the function wouldn't run until I clicked the h1-tag, but idk

Comment: added explanation

Comment: legend. Thank you so much